# Databinding change button color at runtime

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have 3 button in my fragment the process goes this way -

When I click the first button the *rest of the two background color will change to color silver* and the button first button, being click will change to background color blue or light blue indicating your active click button.

Using (`button = findviewbyid`) its relatively easy to change this button properties, such as color at runtime but I want to use `databinding` library,

How to achieve this?

Comment: Show what you have tried in code...

Answer (score 3):

Make one model class and take one boolean value for check click or not when is click used on button click make condition like this ..

In Button xml put below code.

```
android:background="@{model.online == true ? @color/colorAccent : @color/colorPrimary}"
```

pojo class .

```
public class Model {
private boolean isSelected;

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}
```

}

And In xml define variable between data tag..

```
        <variable
        name="model"         type="com.example.adruser.databindinglibrarydemo.model.SampleModel" />
```

make one method in activity .

```
 public void onButtonClick(boolean status) {
    model.setOnline(status);
}
```

then after this method call in button click in xml like this ..

```
  android:onClick="@{()->activity.onButtonClick(false)}"
```

more information you can refer below link :

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Applying-Data-Binding-for-Views

Comment: hey Android Team I am relatively new in MVVM can you please include the ViewModel class that takes boolean value.

Comment: do i need to add  binding.setModel(this) below DataBindingUtils? using "this" or "context" does not work as i am using fragment.

Comment: give getActivity().

Comment: using binding.setModel(getActivity()); i receive an error FragmentActivity cannot convert to model

Comment: binding.setModel(modelclassobject) define. setModel method take model class object paremeter after add some value like name,address using object then that object pass into setmodel.

Comment: is this correct android:background="@{model.isSelected == true ? @color/colorAccent : @color/colorPrimary}"
                android:onClick="@{()->activity.onButtonClick(false)}"    <------- when press the button does not change background color.

Comment: model = new Model(); binding.setModel(model);

Comment: <variable
        name="activity"         type="mypackage.myFragment" />